# jQuery animate - get future position of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the position of an element because my animation is long and $(this).position().top is calculated too early.

How can I get a future position value of an element before it animates to that position?

Comment: Take current position and add the adjustment value you're sending to the `.animate` call?

Comment: The future position isn't a finite value, it's always different.  In this case it's an accordion with text.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what you want. You want to get the position of the element AFTER the animation has completed. You need to add a callback function to your animation, and call the position from inside that callback function. Here you go ->

```
$("whatever").animate({
  //do stuff for animation
}, 'delay', function(){
  //our animation has completed, this is our callback function.
  //we can now successfully get our position.
  $(this).position().top
});
```

Hope this helps!

- Also

Please consider improving your accept rating, 20% either means that your questions are poorly formatted, or you aren't following the community guidelines. Please read the FAQ to understand interacting with Stackoverflow.com

> https://stackoverflow.com/faq

- Side note:

You will also get the badge 'Analytical' for reading the entire FAQ. I highly suggest it.

Comment: I don't need the position of an element once the animation finishes.  I need the end position of an element before the animation start.


P.S.
My questions are poorly formatted thanks.  I'm fairly new at this and I don't have the terminology down pat.  If I don't receive an answer that works but is helpful I'll click the up arrow giving them a +1.

Comment: No problem. I suppose I'm having difficulty understanding what the issue is. $(this).position().top will give you the margin you are from the nearest container that has a position:relative (nearest 'offset parent') on it.Is that what you want? Or do you want the position relative to the document? the window?